$\operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{e^{\pi}} \right)$ as a limit of a sum
Working on the same lines as

This/This and
This

I got the following expression for the Dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{e^{\pi}} \right)$:
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{e^{\pi}} \right) = -\frac{\pi^2}{12} -\pi + 
\\
\pi \lim_{N\to \infty} \left \{ \pi N(N+1) -(2N+1)\log(2N) + 
\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} [-4k\tan^{-1}(2k) + \log(4k^2+1)] \right \}$$
Questions:

Is this type of result known?
Is there a way to simplify the expression further?

Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician and very often I come up with stuff that is well known to mathematicians due to my limited exposure to some topics. If this is well known or a trivial result, please advice on closing the thread, unless you think the responses may be useful to others.
$\color{red}{\mathbf{\text{Edit based on Mariusz Iwaniuk's comment}}}$
$$\operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{e^{\pi}} \right) = -\frac{\pi^2}{12} + \pi \{\log(\operatorname{sinh}(\frac{\pi}{2}))+\log(2)-1\} + 
\\
\pi \lim_{N\to \infty} \left \{ \pi N(N+1) -2N + 
\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} -4k\tan^{-1}(2k)  \right \}$$

Numerically your formula seems ok.

$$\sum _{k=1}^n \log \left(4 k^2+1\right)=n \log (4)+\log \left(\Gamma \left(\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)+n\right)\right)+\log \left(\frac{2 \Gamma
\left(\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)+n\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{\pi }\right)$$

$\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-\pi }\right)$ this is a simple form ,you can't more simplify.

@MariuszIwaniuk
This is an useful result. When I series expand your expression at $n=\infty$, I get $2\log(2)+\log(\operatorname{sinh}(\frac{\pi}{2}))-2n+2n\log(2)+\log(n)+2n\log(n)$.
If you have a similar closed form for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\tan^{-1}(2k)$, we could combine these terms with my rhs in the question and see where it leads to.

No I haven't,but: $$\sum {k=1}^n k \tan ^{-1}(2 k)=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{4 x^2}+\frac{n}{2 x^2}-\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{2 x}\right)}{8 x^3}+\frac{i H{n-\frac{i}{2 x}}}{8 x^3}-\frac{i
H_{n+\frac{i}{2 x}}}{8 x^3}\right) , dx$$, if you integrate: $\int \frac{\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{2 x}\right)}{8 x^3} , dx=-\frac{\pi }{16 x^2}-\frac{\log \left(1-e^{-\frac{\pi }{x}}\right)}{4 x}+\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-\frac{\pi
}{x}}\right)}{4 \pi }$ .The cycle repeats itself and you again get $\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-\pi }\right)$.

Nevvertheless, a beautiful addition to this question, that deserves a special mention. I have edited my question based on your previous comment. I checked that my expression is still numerically correct. Let's see if other experts can take this forward.

With Abel-Plana formula :$$\sum _{k=1}^n k \tan ^{-1}(2 k)\approx \frac{1}{8} \left(2-2 n-\tan ^{-1}(2)+(1+2 n)^2 \tan ^{-1}(2 n)\right)$$ is a good approximation without complicated integral.

If I expand your last expression around $n=\infty$, the $n$ terms nicely and exactly cancel out, leaving only constants (and it looked exciting), but unfortunately, the error is very high. The expression I get with that is $\frac{-\pi^{2}}{3}+\pi(\log(\operatorname{sinh}(\frac{\pi}{2}))+\log(2)-1+\frac{\tan^{-1}(2)}{2}) \approx 0.10366 \gt\gt 0.04369$

@MariuszIwaniuk. I think that there are more sophisticated versions of Abel-Plana summation.  https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#E2 is interesting. Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici, you might want to peek at this thread, where I asked this exact question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4943862/abel-plana-vs-euler-maclaurin-summation-for-s-sum-limits-k-1-infty-left?noredirect=1#comment10570236_4943862

@MariuszIwaniuk, please paste your comments above in the form of an answer. Even if we will never get a closed form, your answer is the one that is closest in the spirit of my goal and question. Unless someone else can crack it, I will accept your answer and award the bounty on it. Claude Leibovici, I really appreciate your attention to this question. Hope you might be able to shed some light in the thread that I linked to, possibly showing what you get with your improved Abel-Plana as well.

First begin noting that by expanding at infinity, we have
$$2\pi k - 2 - 4k\arctan(2k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n 2^{1-2n}}{(2n+1)k^{2n}}.$$ This means that \begin{align*}\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\pi N(N+1)-2N+\sum_{k=1}^{N}-4k\arctan(2k)\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(2\pi k-2-4k\arctan(2k)\right)\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n 2^{1-2n}}{(2n+1)k^{2n}}\\ &=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2n+1}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{2n}.\end{align*} Now recall that $$1-\pi x\cot(\pi x)=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)x^{2n},$$ meaning that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{i}{2}}\left(1-\pi x\cot(\pi x)\right)\mathrm{d}x=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2n+1}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{2n+1}.$$ Hence, \begin{align*}\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\pi N(N+1)-2N+\sum_{k=1}^{N}-4k\arctan(2k)\right)&=\frac{2}{i}\int_{0}^{\frac{i}{2}}\left(1-\pi x\cot(\pi x)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\ &=-2ix+\pi x^2+2ix\log\left(1-e^{2\pi i x}\right)+\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{2\pi i x}\right)\bigg]_{0}^{\frac{i}{2}}\\ &=1+\frac{7\pi}{12}-\log\left(e^{\pi}-1\right)+\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{-\pi}\right).\end{align*} After some rearrangement, we obtain your identity. $\square$

To answer your two questions:
As can be seen above, it's not hard to determine this result so it wouldn't surprise me if it's already known. It cannot be simplified further as $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{-\pi}\right)$ is not known to have a closed form.

Since
$$I=\int \Big(\log \left(4 k^2+1\right)-4\, k\, \tan ^{-1}(2 k)\Big)\,dk$$
$$I=k \left(\log \left(4k^2+1\right)-1\right)+\left(2 k^2-\frac{1}{2}\right) \tan^{-1}(2 k)$$
using the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$\text{rhs}=\pi  \left(\frac{4937327}{4921875}-\frac{1}{2}\log (5)-\frac{1}{6} \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)+\frac{\pi }{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
This gives $$\text{rhs}=\color{red}{0.0436}55$$ corresponding to a relative error of $0.08$%.

Not an answer. Too long for comment and might distract if added in the question as edit.
I tried to get a closed form of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}[-4k\tan^{-1}(2k)+\log(4k^2+1)]$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}[-4k\tan^{-1}(2k)+\log(4k^2+1)] = -4 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \int\limits_{0}^{k} \tan^{-1}(2x) dx = I$$
$$I = -4 \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \tan^{-1}(2x) S_{N}(x)$$
Here, $S_{N}(x)$ is a staircase defined as
$$
 S_{N}(x) =
\begin{cases}
N,  & 0\le x \lt 1 \\
N-1, & 1 \le x \lt 2 \\
N-2, & 2 \le x \lt 3 \\
... \\
1, & N-1 \le x \lt N \\
0, & \text{elsewhere} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then I created an odd-symmetry signal $M_{N}$ by flipping $S_{N}$ horizontally around y-axis and vertically on x-axis and adding to $S_{N}$.
$$M_{N}(x) = S_{N}(x)-S_{N}(-x)$$
So, $$I=-2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tan^{-1}(2x) M_{N}(x)$$
Now, let us use Fourier Transforms and then use Parseval Identity.
Fourier Transform formula I use is $FT[f(x)](y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i2 \pi x y}dx$
With this, $$FT[\tan^{-1}(2x)](y) = -i \frac{e^{-|\pi y|}}{2y}$$ and
$$FT[M_{N}(x)](y) = \frac{i}{2} \operatorname{sinc}(\pi y) \operatorname{csc}(\pi y)[\operatorname{csc}(\pi y) \sin\{(2N+1) \pi y\} -2N-1]$$
Using Parseval Identity ($\color{red}{\mathbf{\text{Edit: Plancherel/Parseval identity is}}}$ $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\xi) \overline{\hat{g}(\xi)} d\xi$. I had overlooked the conjugate and hence removing the negative sign I had earlier.),
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-|\pi y|}}{y} \operatorname{sinc}(\pi y) \operatorname{csc}(\pi y)[\operatorname{csc}(\pi y) \sin\{(2N+1) \pi y\} -2N-1] dy$$
Because the integrand is even,
$$I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-|\pi y|}}{y} \operatorname{sinc}(\pi y) \operatorname{csc}(\pi y)[\operatorname{csc}(\pi y) \sin\{(2N+1) \pi y\} -2N-1] dy$$
Substituting $\pi y = t$,
$$I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \operatorname{sinc}(t) \operatorname{csc}(t)[\operatorname{csc}(t) \sin\{(2N+1) t\} -2N-1] dt$$
Expand $\operatorname{sinc}(t)$ as $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ to get rid of one $\operatorname{csc}(t)$.
$$I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}  [\operatorname{csc}(t) \sin\{(2N+1) t\} -2N-1] dt$$
Note: I have verified that this integral is accurate by comparing it for small values of $N$.
I haven't proceeded much afer this. Mathematica cannot give me a closed form of this (which I know will diverge when $N \to \infty$). The hope is to get a closed form from this without summations (and most importantly not bring back the Polylog I am solving) and then do a series expansion at $N = \infty$ and plug it back into my original question in the place of my summation that I currently have. I again hope that such a series will be in terms of logarithms that might hopefully be amenable to a limit calculations. Enough of my hopes. I request all the integration masters on this site to help solving this integral if you find the above steps useful, or else, give another closed form for my original summation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}[-4k\tan^{-1}(2k)+\log(4k^2+1)]$
