Abel-Plana vs Euler-MacLaurin summation for $S = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[ 2 \pi k - 2 - 4k \tan^{-1}(2k)\right]$
I have a sum as follows:
$$S = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2 \pi k - 2 - 4k \tan^{-1}(2k) \approx -0.250854$$
$$S=2+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 2 \pi k - 2 - 4k \tan^{-1}(2k)$$
Applying Euler-MacLaurin summation with $f(x) = 2 \pi x - 2 - 4x \tan^{-1}(2x)$ and $P_{2}(x) = (x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor)^{2}-(x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor)+\frac16$
$$
\begin{align}
S_{EM} & = 2 + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx + \frac{f(\infty)+f(0)}{2}+ \frac16 \frac{f^{'}(\infty)-f^{'}(0)}{2!} - \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f^{"}(x)\frac{P_{2}(x)}{2!} dx \\
& = 1-\frac{5\pi}{12} - \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f^{"}(x)\frac{P_{2}(x)}{2!} \\
\end{align}
$$
Applying Abel-Plana summation:
$$
\begin{align}
S_{AP} & = 2 + \frac{f(0)}{2} + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx + i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(i t)-f(-i t)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt \\
& = 1-\frac{5\pi}{12} \\
\end{align}
$$
Assumptions:

To apply Abel-Plana, $f(x)$ needs to be holomorphic for $Re(x) \gt 0$. Here the branch points of $f(x)$ are at $\frac{i}{2}$ and $-\frac{i}{2}$. So I am assuming this is satisifed.
To apply Abel-Plana, $|f(x)|$ needs to be bounded, which seems to be the case. I haven't rigorously validated this assumption.

Questions

Are my assumptions regarding Abel-Plana right for my function?
Is the remainder term seen in Euler-MacLaurin also present in Abel-Plana (but omitted for simplicity)? I am simply following Wikipedia for the definition and it doesn't mention the remainder term as in the wiki page on Euler-MacLaurin.

I am new to both of these and self-learning. Apologies about any basic mistakes.

This is a “better” Abel—Plana version.

@FelixMarin $f^{"}(x) = -\frac{16}{(4x^2+1)^{2}}$. So $f^{"}(\infty+i V_{n} y) = 0$ for arbitrary $V_{n}$ in $(0,1)$. So the complicated last integral vanishes. The rest of the stuff again gives $1 - \frac{5 \pi}{12}$. Sad. Can someone shed some light as to what's going on?
